# Creating domain events only for the purpose of making the projection logic less complex

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

In an event sourced system, I'm curious as to what people think about when it comes to introducing extra events - or extending events, only for the purpose of making the projection logic less complex. I have to admin it feels a bit wrong.

Simple example:

OrderPlaced(orderId, orderLines) where OrderLine(lineId, productId, price)

OrderAccepted(orderId)

And if I want a projection to sum up all the prices for each product - but only for accepted orders. So if I choose the approach where I extend (or introduce new) events, I would for example need to extend OrderAccepted so it adds the order lines. If I choose not to extend the OrderAccepted, then the projection would need to hold all placed order lines for the specific product.

Keep in mind this is a simple example - the actual problem at hand is more complex. I feel like the last approach is the way to go - but would like some input on this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at it from a single responsibility point of view, what is the responsibility of the event? It is to carry information about what happened.
In case of `OrderPlaced` we notify interested parties that new order appeared in the system, and we provide the `Order` itself in the event.

In case of `OrderAccepted` we notify that order with the ID was accepted. Nothing happened with order lines in this case, so they are not the part of the event, and we don't need to include them. This makes the event history readable and understandable.

It will also give you a consistent way of projecting current entity state from events - every event contains only changes to the entity.

I agree with you on that the projection should compute what is needed for it without extending the events.